# UIView frame.size.width is equal to zero?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, subclass

I created a subclass of UIView and within the subclass I try to access the views' width property. I try to get the width like this,

```
CGFloat width = self.frame.size.width;
NSLog(@"Width: %f", width);
```

However for some reason the width I'm getting is equal to 0.000000

When I create the view I'm setting the frame property using the CGRectMake() function and the view is clearly displaying properly so why would the width property return zero?

Comment: looking at the sequence of UIPicker related questions, i am tempted to ask the intention behind this task. Reason is, what you want to achieve might be having a better. Did you check the usage of inputViews and inputAccessoryViews and are you sure they wont help ?

Comment: @cgossain you probably need to include more code to let us know what is happening. also, have you debugged to determine that your frame setting code is getting called with the values you think it should be.

Comment: It turns out that at the point where I was asking for the UIView's frame, the frame had not been set yet. I was calling the line in my custom -init method which I should have noticed. In any case I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you subclass UIPickerView, irrespective of the frame you set, width and height are 320,216 (for Portrait).
Make sure `self` in your code points to the picker.

Comment: I made a mistake in my question. I actually subclassed uiview and I have a picker view inside. I want the width property of the view to set the width property of the picker to the same thing.

Comment: @cgossain Please select the answer if the solution helped you. Also did you check the comments ? Are you sure that you want behavior other than inputView and accessoryView ?

Comment: unfortunately that did not help. I'm still getting zero for the width

Comment: I was trying to get the value of the width in my custom -init method while the frame had not yet been set yet. I'm using the setFrame: setter now and that's working.

Answer (score 0):

Try **`CGFloat width = self.view.frame.size.width;`**

Comment: @cgossain subclassed UIPickerView and probably it is not ViewController but a View.

Comment: Its harsh to downvote, with the limited info provided, @WrightsCS might have guessed , the actual implementation is a ViewController and not View (which seems the correct implementation). please edit your answer.

Comment: I believe it is right to downvote a technically incorrect answer. If the answer is corrected then the vote can be changed. The author also has the option of deleting the answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/why-do-you-cast-downvotes-on-answers

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this @cgossain?

```
CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds);
CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds);
```